# Nunit parameterization with C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I'm looking for a little bit of help in understanding NUnit when used with C# and Selenium in visual studio.

I've built a suite of tests where a lot of it has been cobbled together via self-learning and youtube videos.

The project used to just need to be a series of regression tests that run against a single site in multiple browsers.

I've achieved this and am quite happy with the results.

What I want to do now is expand this a little further

The product I have been testing against is a website that is reskinned for different clients where 99% of the content is the same.

Instead of just creating multiple projects/solutions in visual studio, I'd like to do something a bit more dynamic to cover regression against the different skins.

What i would like to do, is parametrize the testcase/browser/url combinations e.g.

- TestCase1/Chrome/Site1
- TestCase1/Chrome/Site2
- TestCase1/Edge/Site1
- TestCase1/Edge/Site2 etc.

I've been able to get the Visual Studio Test Explorer to recognize the parameter, but for some reason, it seems to produce un unexpected result e.g.

- TestCase1/Site1
- testcase1/Chrome
- TestCase1/Site2
- TestCase1/Edge/etc.

I've seen forums where they discuss doing something similar to what I'm talking about here by using NUnit parameters but have not been able to produce the desired result.

I thought it would have simply been a case of just adding another NUnit pram and passing it as I did before. Here is a `slimmed down` version of the code I'm currently using:

```
namespace AutomationStuffs.SmokeTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class LoginTests : TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestBase), "BrowserToRunWith")]
        public void FirstTimeLogin(String BrowserName, String Url)
        {
            //Browser Driver Setup For test
            Setup(BrowserName);

            //...DO SOME TESTING THINGS
        }
    }
}

namespace AutomationStuffs.Utilities
{
    public class TestBase
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver;

        public void Setup(String BrowserName)
        {
            Driver.Intialize(BrowserName);
            //... DO SOME SETUP STUFF
            LoginPage.GoTo();
            //..I DO SOME LOGIN SETUP HERE
        }


        public static IEnumerable<String> BrowserToRunWith()
        {
            String[] browsers = BrowsersList.theBrowserList.Split(',');
            foreach (String b in browsers)
            {
                yield return b;
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace AutomationStuffs.Pages
{
    public class LoginPage
    {
        public static void GoTo()
        {
            Driver.Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl(Driver.baseURL);
        }
    }
}


namespace AutomationStuffs.Selenium
{
    public class Driver
    {
        public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }
        public static string baseURL
        {
            get
            {
                string url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"];
                return url;
            }
        }

        public static string chromeDriver
        {
            get
            {
                string driver = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChromeDriver"];
                driver = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, driver);
                return driver;
            }
        }

        public static string ieDriver
        {
            get
            {
                string driver = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IEDriver"];
                driver = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, driver);
                return driver;
            }
        }


        public static string edgeDriver
        {
            get
            {
                string driver = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EdgeDriver"];
                driver = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, driver);
                return driver;
            }
        }

        public static void Intialize(String BrowserName)
        {
            String DRIVER_PATH = chromeDriver;
            String DRIVER_PATH_IEFF = ieDriver;
            String DRIVER_PATH_EDGE = edgeDriver;

            var optionsChrome = new ChromeOptions();
            optionsChrome.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            optionsChrome.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

            var optionsIe = new InternetExplorerOptions();

            if (BrowserName.Equals("ie"))
            {
                Instance = new InternetExplorerDriver(DRIVER_PATH_IEFF);
                Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            }
            else if (BrowserName.Equals("firefox"))
            {
                Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
                Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            }
            else if (BrowserName.Equals("edge"))
            {
                Instance = new EdgeDriver(DRIVER_PATH_EDGE);
                Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            }
            else
            {
                Instance = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH, optionsChrome);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I thought I would have to do (And obviously just duplicate and adapt the underlying methods where appropriate):

```
namespace AutomationStuffs.SmokeTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    //[Parallelizable]
    public class LoginTests : TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestBase), "BrowserToRunWith")]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestBase), "URLToRunWith")]
        public void FirstTimeLogin(String BrowserName, String Url)
        {
            //Browser Driver Setup For test
            Setup(BrowserName);

            Assert.IsTrue(FiveComponentsAndDocStorePage.AssertOnThePage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUnit treats every `TestCaseSource` separately, it will creates test cases for `BrowserToRunWith` and only after that it will do it for `URLToRunWith`. If you try to run it you will get

> Result Message:   Wrong number of arguments provided

To create test cases for both parameters you need to send them together to the `TestCaseSource`. You can do something like

```
public static IEnumerable TestData
{
    get
    {
        string[] browsers = BrowsersList.theBrowserList.Split(',')
        string[] urls = UrlsList.theUrlList.Split(',')

        foreach (string browser in browsers)
        {
            foreach (string url in urls)
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(browser, url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or with linq

```
public static IEnumerable TestData
{
    get
    {
        string[] browsers = BrowsersList.theBrowserList.Split(',')
        string[] urls = UrlsList.theUrlList.Split(',')

        return from browser in browsers
               from url in urls
               select new TestCaseData(browser, url);
    }
}
```

And the `TestCaseSource` will look like

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(AAA), "TestData")]
```

Comment: That is a spot on answer! Thank you so much. I was running under the very incorrect impression that I could just pass the TestCaseSource value again and NUnit did some magic - obviously, I was very wrong ha, ha.

Answer (score 1):

@Guy 's answer is exactly correct - I up-voted it.

For completeness, here is an alternative way to write the test, which may be what you had in mind when you thought NUnit would "do some magic."

```
    [Test]
    public void FirstTimeLogin(
        [ValueSource("BrowserToRunWith")] String BrowserName, 
        [ValueSource("UrlToRunWith")] String Url)
    {
        //Browser Driver Setup For test
        Setup(BrowserName);

        Assert.IsTrue(FiveComponentsAndDocStorePage.AssertOnThePage());
    }
```

The ValueSource members would be similar to what you already have but would each return a `string` rather than a `TestCaseData` instance.

Note that the `[Test]` attribute is required in this case. It was optional (and ugly, IMO!) in the original example. :-)

Comment: That's very useful to know. Thank you for this.